# Why does this solution state that the line integral over a certain closed curve is not zero?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Below is a question from a practice exam for my college's Calc 3 final. The solution is shown.

[image]

We have that $F(x,y)$ is a conservative vector field. It follows that the line integral of $F$ over any smooth curve is path-independent.

But both $C$ and $D$ are closed and smooth curves, so shouldn't $\int_CF \, \mathrm{d}r = \int_D F \, \mathrm{d}r = 0$?

The solution asserts $I_D = 0$, but not that $I_C = 0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F$ isn't even defined at $(0,0)$, so the domain of $F$ is an annulus, not the plane.  The solution mentions "simply connected", which is your hint: the circle $C$ cannot be collapsed to a point in the domain of $F$ because it is obstructed by the deleted origin but the circle $D$ does not enclose the origin, so does collapse to a point ($=$ simply connected).

Another way to see this is that there is no way to ensure $F$ is conservative at $(0,0)$, so you shouldn't just assume that it is.  And this means you do not get to use the computational shortcut for any path that encloses the origin.